# int is not an interable?

Tags: python, function

trying to make an average function myself as requested by a book I'm using to learn python. This is what I have and I need it to basically have a requirement of at least 1 argument to avoid division by zero, but to accept any amount of other arguments. But I keep getting this error. Here's my code. Any help is appreciated!

```
    1 def average(x, *args):
----> 2     return sum(x, *args) / len(x, *args)
      3 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you show your call to `average`? It looks like you should call it `average([1,2,3])` for example. I'm guessing you probably tried `average(1,2,3)`?

Comment: You cannot pass a number as first argument to `sum`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum . Same for `len`.

Comment: And what do you need the `*args` for? For the `sum` function, this would be the zero element if you need to add other than numbers, but it doesn't make sense for `len`, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum()` and `len()` only take in iterables, which are objects that python can iterate through, like strings, lists, sets, etc.

You need to close the integers with brackets, so it would be a list, and then, you can put the iterable into `sum()` and `len()`.

```
def average(x, *args):
    return sum([x, *args]) / len([x, *args])

print(average(1, 4, 2, 6))
```

Output:

```
3.25
```

Comment: Very simple, short, and sweet to the point. Also thanks for explaining it the way you did. It really helped me understand what my error was saying.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `sum` nor `len` take an arbitrary number of arguments. If you want `average` to do so, you need to pass them all as a single iterable to `sum` and as a single object (that supports the length protocol) to `len`.

```
def average(x, *args):
    all_nums = [x]
    all_nums.extend(args)
    return sum(all_nums)/len(all_nums)
```

(I suppose `all_nums = [x, *args]` would work as well; I spend too much time in Python 2 for that to feel natural yet.)

If you wanted `average` to be more like `sum` and take an arbitrary iterable, it would be easier to compute the sum and length in parallel, rather than use `sum` directly (since `len` does not work with arbitrary iterables)

```
def average(nums):
    length = 0
    total = 0
    for x in nums:
        length += 1
        total += x
    return total/length
```

Comment: Definitely works! Thanks for answering!